# Wordpress SQL Questions

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a problem, I would like to know how to combine this query to perform a search

```
SELECT user_id
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key =  'g_State'
AND meta_value LIKE  '%Pahang%'
```

with

```
SELECT user_id
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key =  'g_Categories'
AND meta_value LIKE  '%cat001%'
AND meta_value LIKE  '%cat002%'
```

is it possible to do it without changing the structure of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE (meta_key = 'g_State' AND meta_value LIKE '%Pahang%')
   OR (meta_key = 'g_Categories' AND 
       meta_value LIKE '%cat001%' AND meta_value LIKE '%cat002%')
```

Comment: Im so sorry. its not just combine, but it will filter which user has those value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the results, rewrite your where clause:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE (meta_key = 'g_State' AND meta_value LIKE '%Pahang%') OR (meta_key = 'g_Categories' AND meta_value LIKE '%cat001%' AND meta_value LIKE '%cat002%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE (meta_key =  'g_State'
AND meta_value LIKE  'Pahang' + '%')
OR
(meta_key =  'g_Categories'
AND meta_value LIKE  'cat001' + '%'
AND meta_value LIKE  'cat002%' + '%')
```